# Back-quote identifier within interpolated string

Tags: scala

Say I use an arbitrary identifier as field name:

```
object A { val `type` = "x" }
```

How can I refer to it in an interpolated string?

I tried

```
object A { 
  val `type` = "x"
  override def toString() = s"$type"
}
```

but got a compiler error:

```
error: error in interpolated string: identifier or block expected
    override def toString() = s"$type"
```

and if I try

```
object A { 
  val `type` = "x"
  override def toString() = s"$`type`"
}
```

I get

```
error: invalid string interpolation: `$$', `$'ident or `$'BlockExpr expected
    override def toString() = s"$`type`"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution, have to put the back-quote identifier in braces:

```
object A { 
  val `type` = "x"
  override def toString() = s"${`type`}"
}
```

Comment: There was a suggestion to take arbitrary identifiers in interpolations, but this twist didn't come up. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4663

Comment: The doc does say `s"$id"` expands to `s"${id}"` so `s"$type"` correctly doesn't work. But the error message is terrible. http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/string-interpolation.html